# How to handle feed folders in Thunderbird via AddIns?

Tags: rss, thunderbird-addon

I want to build an AddOn for Thunderbird, so RSS feed folders which got forced to "Pause Updates", due to errors while fetching the feed, get unpaused automatically after a defined period of time (since Thunderbird itself isn't providing that functionality).

Is there any way to handle this information via an AddIn?

Internally, there's a FeedsUtils, which handles all of that, but what I've read is, that all Thunderbird AddOns need to go through the MailExtensions APIs - which seems okay to me. But, I found a "folders" API, but there's no feed information on these "folder" or "folderInfo" types. Unfortunately - as far as I could see on the documentation site - there is no "feeds" API.

Answer (score 2):

As far of Thunderbird 91.1 there's no "feeds" API.

See the conversation at [thunderbird.topicbox.com](https://thunderbird.topicbox.com/groups/addons/T3b11f5c9a312af61).